# How do I check if a specific module has been added to a Worklet?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-worklet, worklet

I’m working with `AudioWorkletNode` and, to use it, it requires you to first load a processor module on the `audio_context.audioWorklet`.

```
DOMException: Failed to construct 'AudioWorkletNode': AudioWorkletNode cannot be created: AudioWorklet does not have a valid AudioWorkletGlobalScope. Load a script via audioWorklet.addModule() first.
```

---

Due to the modular nature of my code, I need a reliable way to prevent the unnecessary multiple loading of the processor module; not to `.addModule` if already done to a given `AudioContext`. Is there such a way other than *`try`-`catch`ing* and marking on the `AudioContext` object?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have named your processor `my-processor` and the definition of your `AudioWorkletProcessor` looks somehow like this:

```
class MyProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {

    process () {
        return true;
    }

}

registerProcessor('my-processor', MyProcessor);
```

To check if that processor is already loaded you can do something like this from within the main thread:

```
// somewhere inside of an async function ...

let audioWorkletNode;

try {
    audioWorkletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'my-processor');
} catch (err) {
    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('./worklet.js');

    audioWorkletNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'my-processor');
}
```

The code is using a `try`/`catch` block but it does at least not load the JS file if it was already loaded before.